# Move First 10 List Items to Another Item List

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List<Item> OldItems = new List<Item>` and I want to move first 10 items of `OldItems` to `NewItems` which is `List<Item> NewItems= new List<Item>`

Is there something like?

```
NewItems.AddRange(OldItems.<First10Items>);
OldItems.Delete(<First10Items>);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
NewItems.AddRange(OldItems.Take(10));
OldItems = OldItems.Skip(10).ToList();
```

alternate:

```
NewItems.AddRange(OldItems.Take(10));
OldItems.RemoveRange(0,10);
```

Take will take `x` first items from your list [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).
Skip will skip `x` elements from your list [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx). RemoveRange is an alternative option if you will use lists [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx).

As Matthew said second option won't create new list and do removal in-place, so it's prefered.

Comment: That won't compile. OldItems is a List, so you can't assign the result of Skip() to it.

Comment: Whoops, fixing it. I haven't looked at definition. Thanks.

Comment: You also need an `OldItems.RemoveRange(0, 10)`

Comment: @dabide for what? `OldItems` are overwritten. Not need to remove range.

Comment: I think a problem here may be that you haven't removed any items from `OldItems` - instead, you've created a new list with the items removed and assigned `OldItems` to the new list. I think the OP may have wanted an in-place removal (although he doesn't explictly ask that). But if anything else also has a reference to OldItems via a different reference, it will still see the old unmodified list.

Comment: @MatthewWatson good point, thanks. I made second code snippet with `RemoveRange` which will fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
var NewItems = OldItems.GetRange(0, 10);
OldItems.RemoveRange(0, 10);
```

(this doesn't use Linq)

Comment: I don't want to be rude, or something, but there is `linq` tag, so linq answer is prefered :)

Comment: @wudzik That would be an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem though, don't you think?

Comment: You're right, but it's monday, right? :) Thanks for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
List<Item> oldItems = new List<Item>();
List<Item> newItems = new List<Item>();
newItems.AddRange(oldItems.Take(10));//add first 10 items to new list
oldItems.RemoveRange(0, 10);//remove first 10 items from old list
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

```
GetRange(int index, int count); RemoveRange(int index, int count);
```

To implement this.

Answer (score -2):

```
List<string> checkForNull = new List<string>();
        List<string> newList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            checkForNull.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
        }
        for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++)
        {
            newList.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
        }
        checkForNull.AddRange(newList.Take(5));
        newList.RemoveRange(0, 5);
```